# What hash function should to hash an ordered list of numbers?

Tags: function, hash, numbers, sequence, hashcode

Consider a type which is a map of int keys to int values. The keys are ordered less than, and the map can be considered as a flat list { key1, val1, key2, val2, etc. }

I produce a list of these maps, and want to be able to identify identical maps in less than O(n^2) time. I intend to hash each map once to achieve this.

I'm unsure what hash function would be best for this purpose. My keys can be very large numbers (but still int32) and the values tend to be small, though I think such considerations are irrelevant, hopefully there's a hash function I can use which works well for general number sequences.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most hash functions, in particular cryptographic hash functions, work over binary data, so anything which can be represented as a sequence of bytes can be processed. You just have to decide what encoding you will use for your keys of values.

As for the hash function, since your problem is not related to security, you can choose just about any function you wish. Cryptographic hash functions provide extremely good "mixing" and some are very fast (competitive with well-known non-cryptographic hash functions such as CRC32). For instance [MD4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320). But chances are that your programming language (you do not say which you use) already provides a [MD5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) implementation, which is still quite decently fast.